# Getting values from similar nodes using Xpath

Tags: r, xpath

I cant seem to get the right xpath to query "a" tag contains h3. Sample code below

```
<div class="ncatstories">
<a href="valuehere">
<div class="img"></div>
</a>
<h5>valuehere</h5>
<a href="valuehere"><h3>titlehere</h3></a>
</div>
```

I would like to get the href value and the h3 value from the last "a" tag

```
<a href="valuehere"><h3>titlehere</h3></a>]
```

here is my code

```
xpathSApply(data1,"//div[@class='ncatstories' and ./a[contains(h3)]]", function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))
```

where data1 is the whole data document.

however, im getting this error

```
XPath error : Invalid number of arguments
XPath error : Invalid expression
Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ..., namespaces = namespaces,  : 
error evaluating xpath expression //div[@class='ncatstories' and ./a[contains(h3)]]
```

Any ideas what i need to do? thanks!

Comment: I'm no xpath geek, but what about `xpathSApply(doc,"//div[@class='ncatstories']/a/h3/..", function(x) c(xmlValue(x), xmlAttrs(x)[["href"]]))`?

Comment: or even `concat(//a/h3, '|', //a[h3]/@href)` returns `String='titlehere|valuehere'`

Comment: Thanks splash and lukeA! both solves this.

Answer (score 1):

Filter down your div as normal, then filter down the anchor tag appropriately, then get the href!

`//div[@class='ncatstories']/a[count(h3)>0]/@href`

Comment: Im getting an error when i tried to run the code  Error in UseMethod("xmlValue") : 
  no applicable method for 'xmlValue' applied to an object of class "XMLAttributeValue"  Ill just use @lukeA solution above. Thanks for yur help Brent!